# How do I get an Apiresponse for a POST operation in ngrx Effects

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

So i have recently shifted to using the ngrx store to set the states of my application. i have a POST operation that returns a response which gives me a message that I use to show on the snackbar. I want to recreate this in ngrx effects.

This was the function in the service before:

```
 this.inventoryService.addMaterial(this.material).subscribe(response =>{
      this.snackbar.open(response.message, '', {
        duration: 5000,
        panelClass: ['custom-snackbar']
      });
      if(response.status){
        this.closeModalEmitter.next();
        this.router.navigate(['/inventory', 'materials']);
      }
    });
```

This is the code in my Effects file:

```
inventoryPostNewMaterial = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(InventoryActions.POST_MATERIAL),
    switchMap((newMaterial)=>{
      return this.http.post<ApiResponse>(
        this.systemService.localServerUrl + 'Inventory/v4/addMaterial',
        {
          material: newMaterial['payload'],
          userId: this.systemService.user.userId,
          systemId: this.systemService.systemId,
          outletId: this.systemService.outletId,
        }
      );

    })
  )
```

I want your advice on a way to dispatch the effect and also receive the response that I used to get like before.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is easy and you can simply reuse you service for that, you just need to extended one action and probably add a new one. Your first action `POST_MATERIAL` can just carry material data, but it does not need a reducer, it'll just trigger an effect. Then when the side effect if processed you dispatch a new and different action to save the data to the store.

```
inventoryPostNewMaterial = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(InventoryActions.POST_MATERIAL),
  switchMap((newMaterial)=> {
   const material = {
     material: newMaterial,
     userId: this.systemService.user.userId, // or create a function, that will return this at once -> getMaterialParams(material)
     //...
   };
   return this.inventoryService.addMaterial(material);
  }),
  // You have a data from BE, now dispatch an action that will trigger a reducer 
  // and save the data to the store.
  map(result => InventorActions.SAVE_MATERIAL({ material: result }))
)

constructor(private inventoryService: InventoryService, private systemService: SystemService) {}
```

Just a note, you don't dispatch an effect, you dispatch an action. Effects are listening to your actions and act if they match the desired action.

Comment: The whole reason for using the store was to replace the services that I'm currently using. I can make an exception for this but I really want to find a way to do it without the use of a service.

Comment: also the addMaterial service fn is exactly the same as the HTTP request written in the Effect . If i use the service anyway, why not let the post operation be done in the service itself. Also before i dispatch the POST_MATERIAL action i do dispatch another action that updates the State

Comment: I see but honestly, I never seen such approach. I would say that the service offers better reusability and it's easy to test if there is no special magic happening there. But if you want to really get rid of them, just move the methods you call to the effect class. You would be able to access them using `this`